# Where is the Invalid syntax near the comma in this TSQL?

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, linqpad, isnull

I'm not getting results back from a query. At first I thought it was just a bad query - that no data *should* be returned, but now it seems it could be a syntax error that's causing the problem.

When running the Stored Procedure (that the query is a part of) in Visual Studio's Server Explorer, I get data back from the first query, but this one (an update) doesn't return any data (no err msg, but no data, either). Yet, when I try to run just this portion of the Stored Procedure in LINQPad, that bosom companion of coders everywhere declaims that it has discovered the much-dreaded "*Error 102: Incorrect syntax near ','.*"

It points to this line:

```
and ItemCode in (Select ItemCode from UnitProducts where Unit='BIG RED ONE')),'X')
```

...(the only line with a ','), but I don't see what the problem is. I also tried this variation on the theme:

```
and ItemCode in (Select ItemCode from UnitProducts where Unit='BIG RED ONE'),'X'))
```

...but the err msg is the same.

Here is the entire query that I'm trying in LINQPad:

```
isnull((Select top 1 ItemCode 
From PlatypusUnitMapping 
where Unit='BIG RED ONE' 
and MemberNo='42' 
and MemberItemCode= '314IMPie'
and ItemCode in (Select ItemCode from UnitProducts where Unit='BIG RED ONE')),'X')
```

So what is wrong with this? The simpler version of the query works:

```
Select top 1 ItemCode 
From PlatypusUnitMapping 
where Unit='BIG RED ONE' 
and MemberNo='42' 
and MemberItemCode= '314IMPie' 
and ItemCode in 
(Select ItemCode from UnitProducts where Unit='BIG RED ONE')
```

...but I need the "isNull" jazz for a subsequent query. What syntax is invalid, and how can I make it valid/fix it?

### UPDATE

Based on a nudge from NMM, I tried this, too:

```
and (ItemCode in (Select ItemCode from UnitProducts where Unit='BIG RED ONE'))),'X')
```

...but to no avail.

Comment: "Here is the entire query that I'm trying in LINQPad:" but it's not an entire query. In any case, the part you did paste there has a dangling WHERE clause: `Where NHItemCode='X'`.

Comment: Yeah, I 86'd that; it was bad juju.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works, and should run on your SQL Server... Compare to your query and see what is missing:

```
SELECT 
    ISNULL((
        SELECT TOP 1
          TABLE_CATALOG
        FROM
            INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE
            TABLE_SCHEMA='dbo' AND
            COLUMN_DEFAULT IS NULL AND
            IS_NULLABLE='NO' AND
            DATA_TYPE IN (SELECT DISTINCT DATA_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE DATA_TYPE<>'numeric')
    ),'NONE')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
and (ItemCode in (Select ItemCode from UnitProducts where Unit='BIG RED ONE') 
OR ItemCode = 'X')
```

Comment: That's not an "OR" that I need, but a value to return if the query's object is a null. However, you may have a point about the need for a paren betwixt "and" and "ItemCode"...

Comment: oh sorry aobut this OR :D
you cannot start procedure with a isnull
`Select isnull((Select top 1 ItemCode 
From PlatypusUnitMapping 
where Unit='BIG RED ONE' 
and MemberNo='42' 
and MemberItemCode= '314IMPie'
and ItemCode in (Select ItemCode from UnitProducts where Unit='BIG RED ONE')),'X')` will be ok but then I'm not sure do you want with last `Where NHItemCode='X`

Answer (score 1):

What does this go with Where NHItemCode='X'.  The error code is near I have found give you a general area of where the error is.  Most of the time when I get this I have a ) out of place but that Where NHItemCode='X'looks out of place.  Can you comment out just that line and see what happens?  The other way to troubleshoot this is start without the is null and without the in clause.  Then add the in clause run again and then last but not least add the is null around.

Comment: Yeah, the "Where NHItemCode='X'" clause was a mistake, and I removed it; still get the error, though (in LINQPad).